# Can only load dialog once (under some circumstances)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a partial html file with a button that loads another modal dialog. The modal dialog is used to look up some information and return the results to the calling partial form. The button works fine and the search works fine. When I return data back to the partial form and close the search dialog, the button no longer works. Selecting the button again causes the button to perform a post back but it never calls the script again. If I cancel the dialog (with the cancel button) it still works. It's only when I update the form with the posted back data that it breaks.

Here is the script for the modal

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $dialog = $("#AddUserForm")
    .dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        position: { my: "center", at: "top+350", of: window },
        width: 1000,
        resizable: false,
        title: 'Select Corporation',
        modal: true,
        open: function () {
            $(this).load('@Url.Action("FindCorporation", "OutsideClient")');
        },
        buttons: {
            "Select": function () {
                GetCorporationDetails();
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }

    });

$('#btnGetCorps').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $dialog.dialog('open');
});
});
```

And here is what is returned when you click Select

```
<script>
    function GetCorporationDetails() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetNewDirectorshipDetails", "OutsideClient")',
            data: {
                entrynum: $("#corporationval2").val(),
                searchvalue: "",
                lawyerid: ""
            },
            dataType: "html",
            cache: false,
            type: "GET"
        }).done(function (data) {
            $("#newDetails").html(data); //HTML DOM replace *
        });
    };
```

This line from the script seems to cause all the problem

```js
$("#newDetails").html(data); //HTML DOM replace *
```

The code in that line does what it is supposed to do (populates the fields) but after it executes the button no longer works. Somehow it loses the binding to the jquery.

Bty, as far as I can tell, per other similar issues that I researched, this is not a case of trying to create the dialog once it's already created. I create it once only and the button(s) issues Open and Close commands. Also, I can open and close it as often as i like and do as many searches as I like. It's only when I accept the search results and post the results back that it breaks.

The View that has the button which calls the modal looks like this:

```html
@model ODLData.NewOdl.Corporations.CorporationsViewModel
<div id="newDetails" class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h1 class="panel-title">Coverage</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="bottom-align col-md-2">
                Corporation Name:
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.CorporationEntity.CorporateName, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "corporationval" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.EntryNum)
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <button id="btnGetCorps"
                        formnovalidate="formnovalidate"
                        class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></i>
                    &nbsp;Add DirectorShip Modal
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
                <div class="container">
                    <br />
                    <div class="form-inline">
                        <div class="bottom-align col-md-2">
                            Director Type:
                        </div>
                        <div class="bottom align col-md-4">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CorporationEntity.DirectorType, Model.DirectorTypeListItems, new {@class = "form-control directordropdown", @id = "status"})
                        </div>
                        <div class="bottom-align col-md-2">
                            Date lapsed:
                        </div>
                        <div class="bottom align col-md-4">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CorporationEntity.Incorporated, Model.IncorporatedListItems, new { @class = "form-control  directordropdown", @id = "status" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="container">
                    <br />
                    <div class="form-inline">
                        <div class="bottom-align col-md-2">
                            Ownership:
                        </div>
                        <div class="bottom align col-md-4">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CorporationEntity.Ownership, Model.OwnershipListItems, new { @class = "form-control  directordropdown", @id = "status" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="bottom-align col-md-2">
                            Industry:
                        </div>
                        <div class="bottom align col-md-4">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CorporationEntity.Industry, Model.IndustryListItems, new { @class = "form-control  directordropdown", @id = "status" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="container">
                    <br />
                    <div class="form-inline">
                        <div class="bottom-align col-md-2">
                            AssetSize:
                        </div>
                        <div class="bottom align col-md-4">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CorporationEntity.AssetSize, Model.AssetSizeListItems, new { @class = "form-control  directordropdown", @id = "status" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="bottom-align col-md-2">
                            Insured Limit:
                        </div>
                        <div class="bottom align col-md-4">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CorporationEntity.InsuredLimit, Model.InsuredLimitListItems, new { @class = "form-control  directordropdown", @id = "status" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="container">
                    <br />
                    <div class="form-inline">
                        <div class="bottom-align col-md-2">
                            Profitabiity:
                        </div>
                        <div class="bottom align col-md-4">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CorporationEntity.Profitability, Model.ProfitabilityListItems, new { @class = "form-control  directordropdown", @id = "status" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bottom-align col-md-2">
                        Comments:
                    </div>
                    <div class="bottom align col-md-4">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.CorporationEntity.Comments, new { @class = "form-control  directordropdown", @id = "status" })
                        @*Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateLapsed, new { @class = "form-control", @id="datelapsed", htmlAttributes = new { type = "date" } }) *@
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />
        <button id="btnTryAgain"
                class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></i>
            &nbsp;Add DirectorShip Modal
        </button>

        </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <button id="btnSaveDirector"
                        class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"
                        data-pdsa-action="savenew"
                        data-pdsa-val="update">                    >
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></i>
                    &nbsp;Save
                </button>
                <button id="btnCancel"
                        formnovalidate="formnovalidate"
                        class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"
                        data-pdsa-action="cancel">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></i>
                    &nbsp;Return
                </button>
                <button id="btnAddDirectorModa"
                        formnovalidate="formnovalidate"
                        class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"
                        data-pdsa-val=@Model.CorpID>
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></i>
                    &nbsp;Retrieve Details
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For the sake of completeness, I will include the solution. Using a delegate was the way I choose to go. I replaced the click even with:

```
$("#detailsPlace").on("click", '#btnGetCorps', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); $dialog.dialog('open'); });
```

Credit to Jesen

Comment: What does the partial view look like?

Answer (score 0):

The click handler is bound to `btnGetCorps` but this element gets replaced with `$("#newDetails").html(data)`.

You need to either move this button out of the replaced content or use a delegate.

```
$("#static-parent").on("click", "#btnGetCorps", function(e) { ... });
```

Comment: That looks like it. I would vote you up, but I'm too new and they won't let me. Thanks, I would never have got that, I don't think.

Comment: Using a delegate was the way I choose to go. I use the id of the  div that contained the partial view